# How to change django field label text for reset password?

Tags: python, html, django

For the reset password, I was wondering if there is any way to customize the field's label tags.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      <br>
      {{ field }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To edit and customize the label go to your forms.py and add label="" into each field that you would like to change. Example below.


**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Custom Label')
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label='Custom Label')
```

I hope this answers your question.